# Getting a range of data from infinite time series

Tags: java, time-series

I have a map storing the time series data in following format

```
HashMap<Date,Double> infiniteTimeSeries;
```

The variable infiniteTimeSeries can have data from 1AD to even 2100AD.
When the user asks the values between Jan-1-1970 to Jan-1-1972, I need to pick the data corresponding to only the requested time range.

Is there an easy way to do this? Like a library.
I am trying to avoid looping on the map , as the map can even have 100 years of data and iterating like 300000 elements for a short requested time range will affect the performance badly

Kindly please provide your valuable suggestions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) instead of a HashMap.

A TreeMap is sorted, by default, by the natural ordering of its keys. The `java.util.Date` class defines a natural ordering by implementing `Comparable<Date>`.

From the TreeMap, you can get a subset of the map over a range of keys, using [TreeMap.subMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#subMap-K-K-). This version extends from `fromKey` inclusive to `toKey` exclusive. (A sibling allows other options.)

```
public SortedMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey,
                         K toKey)
```

By the way, if you're working in Java 8, you might consider using the new `Instant` class instead of the older Date class. Instant also implements Comparable.